# como hacer una funcion mysqli para un buscador?

Tags: php, mysqli, base-de-datos

Quiero hacer un buscador de contactos de aquellos que son tus amigos únicamente y no otros así como whatsapp lo hace pero no se cómo hacer una tabla SQL para hacer la consulta.

> me pasaron este código pero no me funciona ejemplo:

```
$SQL_DATA = "SELECT * FROM ".T_USERS." WHERE userID LIKE '%$data_search%' OR userID IN(
    SELECT user_one as user_id FROM ".T_FRIENDS." WHERE user_two = $userID UNION
    SELECT user_two as user_id FROM ".T_FRIENDS." WHERE user_one = $userID 
    ) ORDER BY userID DESC LIMIT 10";
```

**Mis tablas**

```
CREATE TABLE `db_user` (
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(170) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Wall` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mail` varchar(170) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sex` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vipdate` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vip` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `banned` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `verified` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `online` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `day` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `month` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**tabla de amigos**

```
CREATE TABLE `db_friends` (
  `friend_ID` int(120) NOT NULL,
  `user_one` int(120) NOT NULL,
  `user_two` int(120) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

---

```
$SQL_DATA = '? mysqli code';

    $sql = mysqli_query($con,$SQL_DATA) or die ("error en la consulta". mysqli_connect_error());
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 0)
    {
       echo 'no hay datos';
    }else{
       echo 'josé';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Retomando la idea expuesta y adaptándola a un ejemplo te propongo la solución siguiente

Una solución, es que tengas dos entidades **Usuario y amigos por nombrarlos de algún modo**

Va a ser una relación de uno a muchos; donde un usuario puede tener muchos amigos; por lo tanto debes tener creada primero la tabla usuarios y posteriormente la tabla amigos

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    status_user TINYINT(1) NOT NULL)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Posteriormente puedes crear una tabla llamada amigos que va a estar vinculada con la primera por una llave foránea que haga unión con el id de la tabla usuarios, así mira

```
CREATE TABLE amigos(
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    numero VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    status_amigo TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_amigos_usuarios FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES 
    usuarios(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

> Explicación, se guarda el id del usuario en la tabla amigos para que
>   así con un INNER JOIN puedas obtener un listado de todos los amigos
>   que tiene un usuario

Finalmente tu JOIN podría quedar de este modo:

```
SELECT amigos.numero, amigos.name, usuarios.name
    FROM usuarios
    JOIN amigos
    ON usuarios.id = amigos.user_id
    WHERE usuarios.id = 1;
```

Con el JOIN anterior al final le agrego el WHERE para pedirle que solo me traiga los amigos del usuario con el id 3

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

> En tu tabla db_users deberías colocar solo la llave foránea que
>   vincularará ambas tablas para que de modo que cada vez que guardes un
>   amigo también debas guardar el id del usuario con el cual esta
>   vinculado; es decir con el cual es amigo

Comment: ok pero si en la tabla de amigos solo tiene sus ID de user como funciona asi arriba puse mis tablas

Comment: revisa la parte de mi código en la tabla amigos donde puse el CONSTRAINT con esa instrucción vinculo ambas tablas, es lo equivalente que deberías hacer en tu tabla db_friends

Comment: espero la explicación final que puse te ayude @sode

Comment: no puedo hacer eso no conosco el como